# Add JAR-File to web-inf/lib folder without including it in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am writing an application server using JBoss. The application gets compiled by Maven and packaged as WAR. Now I want to externalize some classes. I create another maven project, which is packaged as JAR.

The JAR has the correct directory tree, I believe. It contains a `META-INF` directory and the package structure as directories, in which the class files reside.

I read on the web that I can add this JAR into the app server by placing it into `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib` without further mentioning it in the pom.xml of the appserver (at some point these JARs shall be plugins, so adding a dependency in the pom.xml is not an option).

When I compile the server, the JAR gets correctly copied into the WAR under `WEB-INF\lib`, along with other external dependencies.

However, when I try to use the class in the appserver, (writing an `import` statement of such a class is enough), maven will complain that it can't find the class.

I tried to find information on the web, but all I could find was that this is the way it's to be done.

Does anyone know where I could further look for clues what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the jar file into `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib` is cumbersome, and plainly wrong.

The reason that the code does not compile is that maven compiler plugin uses defined source paths and (provided and compile scoped) dependencies.

You could change this, but the result would be hard to understand. Also, you would have to update your jar file (which, BTW has no place in your source code) by hand.

Thats what dependency management is for.

Don't work against your tool. If your project needs classes from this jar, it is a dependency. So declare it as such.

Comment: That just makes sense. However, how do I handle "plugins", i.e. classes that are just to be put somewhere and the server just needs to be redeployed? Does your answer mean, there's no "clean" way of doing this?

Comment: You could just change the scope of your dependency to "provided" to exempt it from being packaged into the .war

Comment: If I'm not wrong I think this is another problem. Probably I want to have a custom ClassLoader that goes through customly added jars and does whatever it needs with it

Comment: @GyroGearless hm that wouldn't solve the problem. I'd still have to add a dependency to the JAR in my pom. I want to circumvent this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about "plugins" then you shouldn't be importing the classes directly in your code anyway. A common approach would be to define another module with interfaces that your plugins will implement, then have both your main webapp and the plugin projects depend on this interface module. In the main app you load plugin classes by reflection and cast them to the appropriate interface(s). That way you don't depend directly on the plugins' concrete classes when compiling the host application.

Comment: Ui okay, so I was asking the wrong question in the first place, thank you, that takes me further :D